# Recycler view with edit and delete

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I I am new to xamarin android, would like to have a recyclerview with edit and delete button. Something like this :[image]

The list item should be clickable and on click of list item the selected recycler item should expand and edit and delete button should be displayed. And on delete the item should be deleted from recyclerview.

Any available control to do this?

Comment: I checked your newest post: [Hide/show buttons inside recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827952/hide-show-buttons-inside-recyclerview), so, have you solved this issue?

Comment: @MSFT yes the issue has been solved.