# Show/Hide views in RecyclerView on any event in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-switch

I have a `Switch` button in toolbar and two `TextViews` in `RecyclerView`.

I want to manage the visibility of one of the `TextViews` in `RecyclerView` based on the state of `Switch`.

I have added `OnCheckedChangeListener` to the `Switch` and am setting a boolean `FLAG` to `TRUE` of `FALSE` here. This `FLAG` value is read in `onBindViewHolder(-,-)` method of the `Adapter` and I am setting the View visibility to `VISIBLE/GONE` based on the `FLAG`.

In MainActivity:

```
Switch switchView;
private boolean switchFlag;

public boolean isSwitchFlag() {
    return switchFlag;
}

public void setSwitchFlag(boolean switchFlag) {
    this.switchFlag = switchFlag;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            setSwitchFlag(isChecked);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //recyclerView.refreshDrawableState()        
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

In Adapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
    if (((MainActivity) mContext).isSwitchFlag()) {
        viewHolder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ...
    }
```

How do I manage to show/hide views in `RecyclerView` on any event in `Toolbar`?

Comment: add a variable for switch in adapter. Add getter(if required) and setter method for that variable, in setter add  **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**  and add new line in setOnCheckedChangeListener **adapter.setSwitch(true); or adapter.setSwitch(true);** as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi @NikulVadher how do I initialise the Switch variable in Adapter class? Switch is in a layout inflated in MainActivity while Adapter has a layout which is for RecyclerView.

Comment: @Sabdeep Yohans you can initialise in constructor of Adapter class by-default you can put  false which is default value of switch, but if switch default value changed in xml **android:checked="true"** then you can initialise with true

Comment: Ok, will try and see. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know it works or not otherwise i'll share the code regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better have a model that contains a field for text and a filed for handling visibility, then pass a list of this model to the recyclerView adapter. see below:

```
class ListItem {
   private String text;
   private boolean isVisible;
   //...put getter and seeter methods
}
```

In the `OnCheckChangeListener` you can change visibilty of items:

```
switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        for (ListItem item: mItems) {
            item.setVisiblity(isChecked);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

And finally, in `onBindViewHolder` section you can handle visibility of items.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    viewHolder.textView.setVisibility(mItems.get(position).isVisible() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    viewHolder.textView.setText(mItems.get(position).getText());
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do I get reference of Switch in Adapter so add the listener there? The problem is Switch ref is in MainActivity and Model ref is in Adapter.

Comment: one other solution I have is to reload the entire RecyclerView from MainActivity onCheckedChanged(-,-)

Comment: @SandeepYohans you don't need to reference of Switch in Adapter. when you change switch the entire list that passed to the adapter will be updated, and when you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` all rows of the list will bind again data. so cause of update the list, then items will be hidden.